# System fails to boof after extending my root partition in kali linux

Tags: boot, kali-linux, fdisk

I deleted and created a new partition with `fdisk` in my Linux in order for me to resize it and reboot my system for it to inform the kernel of the changes in the partition table but the system does not start. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the starting sector entered for the new partition was not exactly the same as the old partition. Note this warning from [the Red Hat instructions on using fdisk](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1190213):

> Warning: If you are recreating a partition in order to allow for more
> room on a mounted file system, ensure you create it with the same
> starting disk sector as before. Otherwise the resize operation will
> not work and the entire file system may be lost.

(Note that gdisk has a somewhat more feature rich capability set than fdisk, so you may want to consider gdisk in the future.)

Answer (score 0):

To try and fix this situation, get yourself a live boot media that contains [`testdisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). Let it scan your disk and see if it can restore your partition table back to working order.

Once your system is back in working order, you can try extending the root partition again, hopefully with better results.